# How to make one to one mapping mybatis

Tags: java, sql, spring, mybatis

**[image: strong text]**

[image]

```
{"txnNo": "TEST12345678",
"txnDate": "2020-11-12 11:52:39.417",
"custID": "CID201000005",
"withCard": "Y"}
```

I'm using spring and the result is like this. How can Connect two beans in spring? It does not show the cart bean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between cardbean and salesbean and TXT_SALES_MAST ? And what are you doing, you need value for PROD_CODE ?
If cardbean and salesben are a foreign key, I hope it help you

```html
<association property="cart" column="PROD_CODE"
            javaType="CartBean" select="<mapper of you>.selectbyId" />
```